# How to validate a new form of poetry?

Tags: poetry

I know a writer, who claims to have developed his own style of poetry, called  Mirror Alphoppbet poetry. This new style looks a bit odd to me but he seems to spread it all over and encourages others to use it in their poems. 
How do I validate that this new form of poetry actually makes sense? Are there any parameters to judge?

Comment: This is a bit vague. Are you asking whether there is a formula to assess the poetic nature of a given text?What do you mean by validate?

Comment: Well, I should mention the exact new form created by him but I can't do that. Its called Mirror Alphoppbet poetry

Comment: I am sorry if this question sounds too vague. Obviously, I am not asking you to give me a formula.

Comment: What do you mean by "new" and "validate?"  (I'm a tentative leave-open vote for now -- there's something interesting here, but it just may not be phrased quite right.)

Comment: That is vague. You know someone who thinks they invented a new kind of poetry and is insisting others use it but you can’t tell us what it is. It might be something very well established that your friend thinks he created. If you can edit it so we can possibly give useful answers, that could be beneficial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no global poetry board that certifies new poetry forms, **nor is there any set criteria for the "validity" of a form**.  If your friend enjoys his new form, and if other people do too, I'm not sure why he would need your approval or validation (or what he would do with it if he got it).

Answer (score 3):

A poet writes with the full artifice of language.

Academics and critics seek connections and dice poems into categories.

At birth, a poem in an unfamiliar style is a poem.  A collection of these becomes a voice.  If copied by others, a genre.